# html mp4 video obscuring other content on bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, video

I am trying to place an mp4 video into the background of a web page, with a container sitting on top displaying the page's content.

The video obscures everything though, even though I have the z-index set on the video css and on the bootstrap container

snippet - https://bootsnipp.com/user/snippets/Q0jbX

Is there a step I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out and **updated the snippet https://bootsnipp.com/user/snippets/Q0jbX with the answer** for anybody experiencing the same.

I added a class that had position:relative in it, and included it in the container, that solved my problem.